# Is arp packet storm happens between two directly linked PCs possible?

Tags: networking, broadcast, arp

Network disconnect issue happens in a system of my company.

Here is the network topolgy:
PC1: two NICs, both static IP address. Data: 10.10.22.11, Control: 10.10.22.10
PC2: two NICs, both static IP address. Data: 10.10.22.101, Control: 10.10.22.100
Default Gateway 10.10.22.11 is set on both side. However I don't think this is necessary, as there is no router or gateway between the two PCs, there directly linked.

A consultant point out, since all the IPs are set in same segment 10.10.22, there could be broadcast storm, which might be the cause of network disconnect.

Is this true? Can broadcast storm happen in directly linked two PCs?

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't be.

Broadcast storms happen when there is a loop in a network.
A packet is forwarded to all ports in a switch and if there is a loop the packets are again sent to the same switch on all ports, amplifying the storm, if there is no network loop there shouldn't be any storm.
I don't see any loop in your configuration so this shouldn't be any broadcast storm.

Identifying broadcast storm is not so hard, just sniff on an interface on the network, and if you see millions of times the same broadcast packet, it should be a broadcast storm.

Comment: Thanks. And do you have any suggestion on how to trouble shooting the network disconnect problem. It seems the more packets running between those IPs, more easly the disconnection happens. I have no clue where to start to debug.

Comment: The best choice is to sniff traffic I think, and try to follow every packet.